# How can access to element or node to xml file from c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CDASchemas\cda\Schemas\CCD.xsl"?>
<!-- The following sample document depicts a fictional character’s health summary. Any resemblance to a real person is coincidental. -->
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">
    <!-- 
********************************************************
CDA Header
********************************************************
-->
    <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1"/> <!-- CCD v1.0 Templates Root -->
    <!-- 
********************************************************
CDA Body
********************************************************
-->
    <component>
        <structuredBody>
<!-- 
********************************************************
Problems section
********************************************************
-->
<component>
<section>
    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.11'/> <!-- Problem section template -->
    <code code="11450-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"/> 
    <title>Problems</title> 
    <text>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Condition</th><th>Effective Dates</th><th>Condition Status</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Asthma</td><td>1950</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pneumonia</td><td>Jan 1997</td><td>Resolved</td></tr>
                <tr><td>"</td><td>Mar 1999</td><td>Resolved</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Myocardial Infarction</td><td>Jan 1997</td><td>Resolved</td></tr>           
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </text>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
            <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.27'/> <!-- Problem act template -->
            <id root="6a2fa88d-4174-4909-aece-db44b60a3abb"/>
            <code nullFlavor="NA"/>
            <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ">
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.28'/> <!-- Problem observation template -->
                    <id root="d11275e7-67ae-11db-bd13-0800200c9a66"/>
                    <code code="ASSERTION" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.4"/>                 
                    <statusCode code="completed"/> 
                    <effectiveTime><low value="1950"/></effectiveTime>
                    <value xsi:type="CD" code="195967001" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Asthma"/>
                    <entryRelationship typeCode="REFR">
                        <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                            <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.50'/> <!-- Problem status observation template -->
                            <code code="33999-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="Status"/>
                            <statusCode code="completed"/>
                            <value xsi:type="CE" code="55561003" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Active"/>
                        </observation>
                    </entryRelationship>
                </observation>
            </entryRelationship>
        </act>  
    </entry>


</section>
</component>
<section>
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.10"/> <!-- Plan of Care section template -->
    <code code="18776-5" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"/>
    <title>Plan</title>
        <text>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr><th>Planned Activity</th><th>Planned Date</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr><td>Pulmonary function test</td><td>April 21, 2000</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </text> 
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="RQO">
            <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.25"/> <!-- Plan of Activity activity template -->
            <id root="9a6d1bac-17d3-4195-89a4-1121bc809b4a"/>
            <code code="23426006" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Pulmonary function test"/>
            <statusCode code="new"/>
            <effectiveTime><center value="20000421"/></effectiveTime>
        </observation>
    </entry>
</section>
</component>
</structuredBody>
</component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

I want to parse this file and I want to access to some element of it. So I have build this code:

```
class Program
{
    static String _TEMPLATE_ID_PROBLEM = "2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.11";
    static String _xmlName = "D:\\Copy michele.castriotta@eresult (3).it\\Projects\\[2015 A] Decipher PCP\\02 - phase 1\\cda ccd\\HL7_CCD_final\\SampleCCDDocument.xml";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var doc = XDocument.Load(_xmlName);

        XElement root = doc.Root;

        //DEVO CERCARE DI SELEZIONARE LA SEZIONE GIUSTA
        IEnumerable<XElement>lista= root.XPathSelectElements("component/structuredBody/component/section");
        foreach (XElement e in lista)
        {
        //to do
        }
    }
}
```

but the list "lista" is every time empty. Where is the error?

Comment: the xml you have shown above seems not _well-formed_. can you pls check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the namespace. All the elements under the root are taken as from the same namespace as tagged on the root.

If you have installed XPathInfo for Visual Studio, then open the xml file from VS, you will notice the xpath info for the section is shown as below:

```
/*[local-name()='ClinicalDocument'][namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
/*[local-name()='component'][namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
/*[local-name()='structuredBody'][namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
/*[local-name()='component'][namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
/*[local-name()='section'][namespace-uri()='urn:hl7-org:v3']
```

Therefore, you have to use the NamespaceManager in the call to select the elements, and you have to specify the prefix for the namespace for each element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(_xmlName);

XElement root = doc.Root;
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("hl7", "urn:hl7-org:v3");

//DEVO CERCARE DI SELEZIONARE LA SEZIONE GIUSTA

IEnumerable<XElement> lista = root.XPathSelectElements("hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component/hl7:section", namespaceManager);
foreach (XElement e in lista)
{
    //to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not well-formed xml. You can try here [xml validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)